# Massive discrepancy between molar mass and atomic radius

Tags: solid-state-physics, atomic-physics, density

Carbon's atomic radius is $r = 0.0914\ \mathrm{nm}$.

Avogadro's number is $N_A = 6.022\times10^{23}$.

Consider a cube with $\sqrt[3]{N_A} = 84,\!446,\!227$ carbon atoms along a side.

This means the side length should be
$$2r\sqrt[3]{N_A} = 0.0154367702\ \mathrm{m}.$$

One gram of carbon has $\frac{1}{12}\ \mathrm{mol}$ atoms which is 1/2.2894284851 per side. Graphite has a density of $2.267\ \mathrm{g/cm^3}$.

Our $1\ \mathrm{mol}$ carbon block has a side length $1.54367702\ \mathrm{cm}$, meaning it has a volume of $3.6784877762\ \mathrm{cm^3}$. Using the density of graphite, this would be $8.3391317886\  \mathrm{g}$ and not the $12\ \mathrm{g}$ we expected. That's $31\%$ error. The density of diamond is $3.515\ \mathrm{g/cm^3}$. Even using that, we would compute a molar mass of $12.9298845333\ \mathrm{g/mol}$.

So, if you multiply Avogardo's number by the radius of a carbon atom to get a volume, the resulting molar volume is vastly different from the measured density values. What is the reason for this discrepancy?

Answer (score 3):

Graphite is not a cubic structure with an atomic spacing of $0.914$ Angstroms.

It contains parallel sheets of atoms separated by $3.35$ Angstroms. Within each sheet, atoms are in a hexagonal lattice. This is the same as two triangular lattices with a spacing of $2.46$ Angstroms. In each triangular lattice, parallel lines of atoms are separated by $2.46 cos(60) = 2.13$ Angstroms.

So a $1$ cm cube of graphite contains $2.99 \times 10^7$ planes of atoms. Each plane contains 2 lattices, each with $4.69 \times 10^7$ rows. Each row contains $4.07 \times 10^7$ atoms. This is $1.14 \times 10^{23}$ atoms, or $0.189$ mole, or $2.27$ g.

The density of graphite from Wikipedia is $2.09- 2.23$ g/cm$^3$. This matches reasonably well.

This image is from PhysicsOpenLab [Graphite Structure](https://physicsopenlab.org/2018/01/31/graphite-structure/)

[image]

Comment: "Reasonably well" so much for a non bullshit answer

Comment: It's the best I have. I am sorry you got so many down votes. It happens. It isn't always deserved.

Comment: @JdjdUdudud  "Reasonably well"  because the question and the geometric solutions  have  uncertainties because they are ignoring the quantum mechanical  state of any solid. In mainstream physics if one had the computational means, a single wave function would describe the solid, and the distance would be estimated in a probability display of $Ψ^*Ψ$ , which means  anumber of measurements of the number you are seeking, each measurement different but contributing to the distribution." "Reasonably well"  is what can be known of a quantum state.